# Wireless Feature of Epson XP-225

Tags: wireless, printing, epson

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.

I have an Epson XP-225. I downloaded the Linux driver off their site. It's working fine from my desktop.

I would like to get the wireless feature to work, but I don't see how to do that. I accessed the printer via the 'Printers' program, but no dice. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you asking about printing or scanning?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm talking about hooking up the wifi function for printing.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to print over wireless network, it is quite easy.

Go to System Settings -> Printers and install new printer.

Select "Network Printer" and your printer will be discovered if it is connected to your router.

The only problem is that this printer does not have a display. I do not know if it is possible to configure SSID and password without Windows or Mac.

You will need to connect it to some Windows or OSX computer and use the printer manual to setup a wireless connection. Then you will be able to use your printer from Ubuntu or any other OS over Wi-Fi.

You can use [this video](http://kb.epson.eu/pf/12/webfiles/Videos/first_installation_Video_Rev1.mp4)

Comment: Ok, getting to a Windows or OSX machine is not going to happen. Is there anyway to get the printer to connect to the wifi via my computer? Right now, the wifi is on, but it is NOT connected to the router. There's no display, so not sure how to do that.

Comment: I do not believe that this is a problem to find a Windows computer for 5 minutes. You will configure your printer once from it and the use it on Ubuntu or any other OS.

Comment: Thanks, but getting a windows machine is not going to happen. Are there any alternative ways to set it up?

Comment: I am afraid there is no other way for this model.

Comment: I had a similar issue with XP-231. Installing the package `printer-driver-escpr` was necessary also